# Where database configuration files are stored?

Tags: jasperserver

I"m trying to find database connection configuration files inside JasperReports Server. If you can tell me where *JR Server* stores database configuration files then it will be great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Internal DB configuration

You can find *JasperReports Server* (*JRS*) internal DB configuration at ***<tomcat>\webapps\jasperserver\META-INF\context.xml*** file.

The sample of this configuration file (of my local *JRS* deployed on *Tomcat*):

```xml
<Context path="/jasperserver" reloadable="false">
  <Resource name="jdbc/jasperserver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
  username="jasperdb" password="password" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" 
  validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" 
  url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jasperserver?useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" 
  factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
  <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

As you can see the username and password stored as just an unencrypted text: `username="jasperdb" password="password"`.

And the db connection string is storing like this: `url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jasperserver`

I used this credentials for DB connect with *pgAdmin* (my local *JRS* is using *Postgres*):

[image: Connection with pgAdmin]

### Where datasources are stored

The table *jijdbcdatasource* contains information about *jdbc* based datasources.

For example, I created the new datasource like this:

[image: Datasource at JRS]

The all parameters were placed at new row of *jijdbcdatasource* table:

[image: The jijdbcdatasource at pgAdmin]

Comment: Thanks Alex, These are basically internal db configrations, I'm looking for the files which contains the configration of database that we create from dialog box UI in jasper server. Do you have any idea where they are stored?

Comment: You are welcome :) I've added info about datasources

Comment: Alex, That's great!! that what I have been looking for, but where  is jijdbcdatasource table on jasper server? from where I can do query on that table? thanks a lot

Comment: The first part of my answer is about where the database is storing. The database has default name **jasperserver**

Comment: I want to execute this query "select * from jijdbcdatasource" but I have no idea from where to execute this query on jasper server, I haven't seen any query window on jasper server.

Comment: I'm using my sql, so jijdbcdatasource table will be inside mysql database?

Comment: Are you using MySQL (not Postgres as at my case) as internal DB for JR Server? If yes, that it should be there

Comment: how i can check which database has been used for internal db jasper server?

Comment: At `<tomcat>\webapps\jasperserver\META-INF\context.xml` file

Comment: following is context.xml text: based on which I tried to connect with pgAdmin, but getting failed: please refer the image that I have posted in your answer section  `<Resource accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/jasperserver" password="postgres" testOnBorrow="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jasperserver" username="postgres" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>`

Comment: i have posted image of pgAdmin in answer section,

Comment: okay, but according to you did I filled everything correct? what's the service name?

Comment: The host name is wrong. Should be: 10.42.204.112 in your case

Comment: and what's service name? is it in context.xml?

Comment: No need to set service name. And you should set the db name: `jasperserver` (maintenance DB)